# Plone Dexterity example without Grok

Tags: plone, dexterity

Does anybody know any good examples of Dexterity-based Contenttypes, without use of Grok?

... just for learning purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grok is kind of just a convenience wrapper around the ZCA. Your types can just be changed to use ZCML or just plain zope. For example, the following:

```py
class View(grok.View):
    grok.context(IProgram)
    grok.require('zope2.View')
```

This would just convert to the following in ZCML:

```xml
<browser:page
    name="view"
    for="IProgram"
    permission="zope2.View"
    class=".yourviewmodule.View"
    template=".yourtemplate.pt"
    />
```

Comment: @hvelarde: Is "Pope" a secret insider term or was it a typo? :-)

Comment: @hvelarde: Fixed what?